# change the MediaRecorder source in android

Tags: android, video-streaming, mediarecorder, encoder

Is it possible to change the source for android MediaRecorder?

I would like to record with a video stream or file instead of camera source,

the most likely method I found is '`MediaRecorder.setVideoSource`',

but it has only two choices: `DEFAULT` and `CAMERA`

Could someone give me a hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend the MediaRecorder, or create a new class, based on the original, as its code may be seen [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/media/MediaRecorder.java). Yet it is just a wrapper for the native library that does the actual work, so if you want to modify the functionality in such a way you might need to build your own costume version of Android.